# Difference between $(command) and `command` in a script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

What is the difference between executing a command like this:

```
var=$(ls -alh /dir)
```

And doing it like this:

```
var=`ls -alh /dir`
```

Is one method able to be used in more interpreters than the other?

Comment: @tarrsalah  Thanks, I didn't search thoroughly enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both `command substitution`

Section 3.5.4 http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

> Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the
>   command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any
>   trailing newlines deleted. Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they
>   may be removed during word splitting. The command substitution $(cat
>   file) can be replaced by the equivalent but faster $(< file).
>
> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash
>   retains its literal meaning except when followed by ‘$’, ‘`’, or ‘\’.
>   The first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command
>   substitution. When using the $(command) form, all characters between
>   the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.
>
> Command substitutions may be nested. To nest when using the backquoted
>   form, escape the inner backquotes with backslashes.
>
> If the substitution appears within double quotes, word splitting and
>   filename expansion are not performed on the results.